# SQL: Nested SELECT with multiple values in a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

In my SQL 2005 DB, I have a table with values stored as IDs with relationships to other tables.  So in my ***MyDBO.warranty*** table, I'm storing product_id instead of product_name in order to save space.  The product_name is stored in ***MyDBO.products***.

When the marketing department pulls the demographic information, the query selects the corresponding name for each ID from related tables (trimmed down for brevity):

```
SELECT w1.warranty_id AS "No.",
       w1.created AS "Register Date" 
       w1.full_name AS "Name", 
       w1.purchase_date AS "Purchased", 
       (
           SELECT p1.product_name
           FROM WarrDBO.products p1 WITH(NOLOCK)
           WHERE p1.product_id = i1.product_id
       ) AS "Product Purchased",
       i1.accessories
FROM WarrDBO.warranty w1
LEFT OUTER JOIN WarrDBO.warranty_info i1
    ON i1.warranty_id = w1.warranty_id
ORDER BY w1.warranty_id ASC
```

Now, my problem is that the "accessories" column on the warranty_info table stores several values:

```
No.     Register Date    Name             Purchased       Accessories
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1500    1/1/2008         Smith, John      Some Product    5,7,9
1501    1/1/2008         Hancock, John    Another         2,3
1502    1/1/2008         Brown, James     And Another     2,9
```

I need to do something similar with "Accessories" that I did with "Product" and pull **accessory_name** from the ***MyDBO.accessories*** table using **accessory_id**.  I'm not sure where to start, because first I'd need to extract the IDs and then somehow concatenate multiple values into a string.  So each line would have "accessoryname1,accessoryname2,accessoryname3":

```
No.     Register Date    Name             Purchased       Accessories
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1500    1/1/2008         Smith, John      Some Product    Case,Bag,Padding
1501    1/1/2008         Hancock, John    Another         Wrap,Label
1502    1/1/2008         Brown, James     And Another     Wrap,Padding
```

How do I do this?

EDIT>> Posting my final code:

I created this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SQL_GTOInc.Split
(
  @delimited varchar(50),
  @delimiter varchar(1)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id INT identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val INT
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(5)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

And updated my code accordingly:

```
SELECT w1.warranty_id, 
       i1.accessories,
       (
           CASE
               WHEN i1.accessories <> '' AND i1.accessories <> 'NULL' AND LEN(i1.accessories) > 0 THEN
                   STUFF(
                       (
                           SELECT ', ' + a1.accessory
                           FROM MyDBO.accessories a1
                           INNER JOIN MyDBO.Split(i1.accessories, ',') a2
                           ON a1.accessory_id = a2.val
                           FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                   )
               ELSE ''
           END
        ) AS "Accessories"
FROM MyDBO.warranty w1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDBO.warranty_info i1
    ON i1.warranty_id = w1.warranty_id
```

Comment: Well, it (should) go without saying, but you shouldn't store an acccessories column in the warranty_info like that.  You should have a join table, Warranty_info_accessories that contains two columns: the warranty_id and the accessory_id.  This would greatly simplify your problem

Comment: I agree, that's what I would have done if I had built the structure.  Unfortunately, the DB author was doing everything he could to save space, and this was one of the methods he used.

Comment: I appreciate all the help guys, and if I could choose more than one answer, I would.  Apparently I was just not reading carefully enough and left off the `FOR XML PATH('')` in my statement, causing the error.  I've applied all the suggestions, and it's not working perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a table valued function that simply splits comma separated string into XML and turns XML nodes to rows.

See:
http://www.kodyaz.com/articles//t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx

Join to accessories through the result of function call, and stuff the result back to comma separated list of names.

Untested code:

```
SELECT w1.warranty_id AS "No.",
       w1.created AS "Register Date" 
       w1.full_name AS "Name", 
       w1.purchase_date AS "Purchased", 
       (
           SELECT p1.product_name
           FROM WarrDBO.products p1 WITH(NOLOCK)
           WHERE p1.product_id = i1.product_id
       ) AS "Product Purchased",
       STUFF(
         (
           SELECT 
             ', ' + a.name
           FROM [table-valued-function](i1.accessories) acc_list 
             INNER JOIN accessories a ON acc_list.id = a.id
           FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''
       ) AS [accessories]
FROM WarrDBO.warranty w1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WarrDBO.warranty_info i1
    ON i1.warranty_id = w1.warranty_id
ORDER BY w1.warranty_id ASC
```

Comment: Tried this, and I'm getting an error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` If I put a where clause and only select a single accessory from the list, it works fine.  I don't think it's going to let me use the function in a subquery as part of a STUFF()

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with your question. Just a note that your original query can also be written, moving the subqery to a join, as:

```
SELECT w1.warranty_id AS "No.",
       w1.created AS "Register Date" 
       w1.full_name AS "Name", 
       w1.purchase_date AS "Purchased", 
       p1.product_name AS "Product Purchased",
       i1.accessories
FROM WarrDBO.warranty w1
INNER JOIN WarrDBO.products p1 
    ON p1.product_id = i1.product_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WarrDBO.warranty_info i1
    ON i1.warranty_id = w1.warranty_id
ORDER BY w1.warranty_id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've been trying to move all those selects down to the INNER JOINs, but I've been having difficulty forming that part.  I have probably 5 such tables I'm pulling from similarly, and adding more than 2 INNER JOINs causes my query to return nothing.  Not sure why.

Comment: A subquery in the `SELECT` list can usually be transformed into a `LEFT` join. Not `INNER` join.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the [FOR XML](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) feature of SQL Server to easily cat strings:

Example from the linked blog post:

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ' ' + Description
    FROM dbo.Brands
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
```

To parse a field that has already been stored as comma delimited you will have to write a UDF that parses the field and returns a table which can then be used with an IN predicate in your WHERE clause. Look [here for starters](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/Parse-a-comma-delimited-list-8.aspx), and [here](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/10/26/quick-t-sql-to-parse-a-delimited-string/).

Comment: Ok, so this would select all the accessories from the accessories table and put them in one string.  But how do I get the accessory IDs from the comma delineated string "2,3,9"?  And once I have that, how to I use those as a condition for the SELECT inside the STUFF?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through that.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a work for a concatenate aggregate function.
In SQL it can be deployed using CLR

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2022